# Configuring the synapse properties file in wso2

Tags: wso2

How to configure the `wso2/repository/conf/synapse.properties` files in wso2? I need to change the `synapse.global_timeout_interval` value but updates to the `synapse.properties` seems to be overridden when the server restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using API manager product and a version that use `deployment.toml` for configurations, you can add following config in `wso2/repository/conf/deployment.toml`.

```
[synapse_properties]
"synapse.global_timeout_interval"=value
```